# Algorithm regarding multiplications between a large number and a small one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given two numbers, one small (constant digits long, say 2) and one large ($n$ digits long). what will the time complexity of the multiplication between these two? The naive way would be on the order of $O(n)$. Since I am aware there is fast multiplication algorithm between two $n$ digits long numbers($O(nln(n))$). Does it imply we also have a way to handle the multiplications between large numbers and small numbers?

Comment: Because it should be much quicker than the multiplication between two $n$ digits numbers, right?

Comment: Certainly one can split the large number up into about $n/\ln n$ smaller numbers, multiply each of those by the small number—which takes $O( n/\ln n \times (\ln n)(\ln\ln n)$ operations using the algorithm you mentioned—and then combine the answers together (which takes less time).

Comment: It really depends on what type of implementation? Are you looking into integers? What are you "counting"? Additions? Digit wise you can not avoid 2n multiplications.

Comment: You're not going to do better than $O(n)$, because it takes that long to read the input and print the output...